# IISExpress with tunneling tool: The request hostname is invalid

Tags: asp.net

I started a very simple ASP.net web api app. on port 8080. 
I used ngrok as a tunneling tool to get a forwarding ip address:[image]

Using postman I posted to the local server with the following request
http://ccf7e40b.ngrok.io/Bot/messages
and get the error: "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.". However replacing the forwarding url with localhost:8080 would work. 
I have seen several other posts with the same error messages get resolved by adding a binding line in Documents\IISExpress\config\appilcationHost.config to bind to a specific port. However I'm already running on 8080 port.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: You can use our free extension "Conveyor" available through Tools -> Extensions in VS.  Conveyor will give you a remote URL and port, that port is what you need to point ngrok to, or you can signup for Conveyor's tunneling service instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use modified hostheaders. So in your case, it should work with:

```
ngrok.exe http -host-header=rewrite localhost:8080
```